# Wrong time in Routes file on Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

My config/app.php has the timezone set us:

```
...
 'timezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
...
```

Which works fine when I use it somewhere like on tinker:

```
Psy Shell v0.10.4 (PHP 7.4.7 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> now()
=> Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1595277419 {#4447
     date: 2020-07-21 02:06:59.522138 Asia/Kolkata (+05:30),
   }
>>> Carbon\Carbon::now()
=> Carbon\Carbon @1595277429 {#4445
     date: 2020-07-21 02:07:09.801135 Asia/Kolkata (+05:30),
   }
>>>
```

But when I echo the same in web.php:

```
Route::get('/time', function(){
    return now();
});
```

Returns time in UTC:

```
"2020-07-20T20:44:32.444592Z"
```

Why is it different in the route file? How can I get the current time in any of the routes files?

Answer (score 2):

You should use controllers for this especially when there is a dynamic part to the view. As part of the application startup routes are loaded and config is loaded. My guess would that routes are loaded before config.

Also you should never use a callable in your routes as this makes it impossible to cache the routes.

I’m also curious if the call to now() from the route only returns the string you provided or if it returns a full Carbon object? Is the working directory in tinker set to your application, just to ensure you are not comparing apples vs oranges.

Comment: You can try on a laravel project. It returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

To get the date with your current timezone.
You can use DateTime, with params DateTimeZone

```
new Datetime("now", new DateTimeZone(config('app.timezone'));
```

And after, format the date.

[DateTime documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php)